# Storing growing lists for each user in a MYSQL table

Tags: mysql

So, I'm new to posting on SO, and relatively new to MYSQL. Be gentle.

I have a problem that is repeated in several areas of my planned project.  I need to store a lot of lists.  I'll try and illustrate with a specific example, but I'm really motivated to solve it effectively and efficiently.

Mathematically, I have an interest in linking each item in one set to a subset of another set of items.

Say I have;

```
users (u1, u2, u3, u4, ..., uN)
```

and they each follow a certain subset of articles;

```
articles (a1, a2, a3, ..., aN)
```

So `u1->(a2, a5, a6)` and `u2->(a3,a9,a14,a112)` etc.

And these linked relationships can be added/removed, and need to be checked rapidly to see if a value is present and joined to other tables etc...

Is it possible to do this in a way that avoids creating a table for each of the lists of linkages?  Bearing in mind I need to do this a lot and I'm worried about having 100k+ tables to accommodate all these lists for each user.

**Other examples:** user subscribes to articles, or users follows other users, or listen to certain topics...

This may be a dumb question, but I'm here to find wisdom.

Open to using any languages or tools.

Comment: You just need to create only two tables
* Users->id,name,etc..
* articles -> id,articleheading,etc,userid

Comment: But how can you determine which article a user is linked to - e.g. subscribes to?  The list is the list of linkages - or pointers to the key of another table.

Comment: via userid you will determine it

Comment: or create another table lists which contains two columns articleid and userid

Comment: Thanks - I've edited the question to make it clearer.  In simple term, for each entry in one table there needs to a list made up of row ids in another table.  This list needs to be able to grow and be of arbitrary length.  I've heard that it's a bad idea to store structured data within a field or else I'd store json or similar in there.  But that comes with a performance overhead when this seems like something the database should be handling...

Comment: Or perhaps I misunderstood you. I think the long list of article IDs and userids is exactly what I need. I just use a query to select all associated with one of the other.

Comment: yes the third table will make you subset of articles that user like or follow. 
You just need to join article and articlelist table on userid to get all the article that user like or follow

Comment: Yes, thanks.  This is quite a different way of thinking to programming.